# What's the best strategy for finding the integers solutions of an hyperbola?

Tags: algebra

I have an hyperbola in this form
$$y = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
(actually in my problem $c = -1$)

and i have to find (at least)one of its integer solutions, I've seen that wolframalpha do it very quickly but i have't found any optimized solutions on the internet.
How can it do it? it just bruteforce all the integers solutions?

I've read about pell's equations but i have no idea how they could help.

Thanks

Comment: Is this about solving it in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Is about solving it in the fastest way (like Wolfram does i suppose)

Comment: This site is about programming in Wolfram Language or using WL based software. Is you question about that or is it about math or algorithms?

Comment: Both but maybe i try to ask on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you have access to software from Wolfram,  other than Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: This will give you 10 solutions: `FindInstance[
 y == (a x + b)/(-x + d) && a != 0 && b != 0 && d != 0 && x != 0 && 
  y != 0, {a, b, d, x, y}, Integers, 10]`

Comment: And this will give you 52277 families of solutions.  `Solve[{y == (a x + b)/(-x + d), -10 < a < 10, -10 < b < 10, -10 < d < 10}, {a, b, d, x, y}, Integers]`.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 0.00076 seconds to get 223 solutions.

In:

```
hybperbola[n_] := Module[{xss},
  xss = Table[{(b + a x)/(d - x), x, a, b, d}, {x, -n, n, 1}, {a, -n, 
     n, 1}, {b, -n, n}, {d, x + 1, n + 1}];
  xss // Flatten[#, 3] & // Select[IntegerQ@*First]]
AbsoluteTiming@hybperbola[2]
```

Out:
[image]